# Ambiguous column reference

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following two models

```
type Stack struct {
    Name             string           `json:"name" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Parameters       []StackParameter `json:"parameters" gorm:"foreignKey:StackName; references: Name; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    ...
}

type StackParameter struct {
    Name         string  `json:"name" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    StackName    string  `json:"stackName" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    DefaultValue *string `json:"defaultValue"`
    Consumed     bool    `json:"consumed"`
}
```

I'm trying to join with StackParameter by doing the following

```
var stack *model.Stack
err := r.db.
    Joins("Parameters").
    First(&stack, "name = ?", name).Error
```

But I'm getting

```
ERROR: column reference "name" is ambiguous (SQLSTATE 42702)
```

UPDATE: If I do `First(&stack, "stacks.name = ?", name).Error` I get the following stack trace

```
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Field on slice Value
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] goroutine 1 [running]:
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] reflect.Value.Field({0x33f9ea0?, 0xc0006f8520?, 0xc000118000?}, 0x3894d00?)
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:1268 +0xe5
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] gorm.io/gorm/schema.(*Field).setupValuerAndSetter.func5({0x7f3c90b36108?, 0x80?}, {0x33f9ea0?, 0xc0006f8520?, 0x0?})
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.2/schema/field.go:502 +0xbd
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] gorm.io/gorm/schema.(*Field).setupValuerAndSetter.func11({0x3fdb430?, 0xc000118000?}, {0x33f9ea0?, 0xc0006f8520?, 0xc00062a11c?}, {0x33aba20?, 0xc000122180?})
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.2/schema/field.go:801 +0x423
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] gorm.io/gorm.(*DB).scanIntoStruct(0xc000564630, {0x3fdff18, 0xc000bb6a00}, {0x3894d00?, 0xc0006f8510?, 0xa?}, {0xc0006f86c0?, 0x9, 0x9}, {0xc0004668c0, ...}, ...)
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.2/scan.go:105 +0x53c
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] gorm.io/gorm.Scan({0x3fdff18, 0xc000bb6a00}, 0xc000564630, 0x0)
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.2/scan.go:328 +0xe57
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] gorm.io/gorm/callbacks.Query(0xc000564630)
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.2/callbacks/query.go:28 +0x115
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] gorm.io/gorm.(*processor).Execute(0xc0008c8410, 0xc000903830?)
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.2/callbacks.go:130 +0x3ce
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] gorm.io/gorm.(*DB).First(0xc0002f0be8?, {0x33aa020?, 0xc000122110}, {0xc00007cc00, 0x2, 0x2})
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.2/finisher_api.go:129 +0x1bc
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] github.com/dhis2-sre/im-manager/pkg/stack.repository.Find({0xc000b90000?}, {0xc0002f0be8, 0x5})
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /src/pkg/stack/repository.go:42 +0x107
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] github.com/dhis2-sre/im-manager/pkg/stack.service.Find(...)
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /src/pkg/stack/service.go:42
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] github.com/dhis2-sre/im-manager/pkg/stack.LoadStacks({0x39c0fe9, 0x8}, {0x3fe0110, 0xc0003a8940})
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /src/pkg/stack/loader.go:45 +0x1b8
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] main.run()
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /src/cmd/serve/main.go:97 +0x995
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager] main.main()
  > [im-manager-tons-6646cf4844-c79rq im-manager]   /src/cmd/serve/main.go:51 +0x19
```

Comment: The "ambiguous" error means that the SQL parser doesn't know which `name` column you are referring to. Do you mean stack.name? Or do you mean stack_parameter.name? To avoid the ambiguousness you should qualify the column's name with the table's name (or table's alias).

Comment: I mean stack.name. And yes, I know that. I'm just not sure how to do so.

Comment: To qualify the column name with the table's name you simply join the table name and the column name with a dot. e.g. if the `Stack` type's table name is `stacks` then the table-qualified column would be `stacks.name`.

Comment: If I do that I get a stack trace. I've updated the question so you can see it

Comment: My guess is that you've declared the `stack` variable which you are passing to `First` as `[]Stack` or `[]*Stack`, i.e. `First` expects a struct argument but you are passing a slice (hence the error message: `call of reflect.Value.Field on slice Value`). Or maybe the error is thrown by gorm trying trying to process the `Stack.Parameters` slice, I'm not sure since I have no idea how `gorm` works.

Comment: Not a bad guess, but no, I left it out for the sake of brevity but I've updated the question once again :-) Also note, the query works just fine if I use Preload instead of Joins

Comment: Uh the `stack` variable is `nil`, I'm not sure that's allowed (maybe gorm handles that, but I wouldn't depend on it). I'd recommend always to initialize your arguments you pass to 3rd-party code to non-nil, unless 3rd-party explicitly requires `nil` (which is unlikely). Either use `stack := new(model.Stack)` and pass `stack` to `First` (without `&` since it's already a pointer), or do `stack := model.Stack{}`/`var stack model.Stack` and pass `&stack` to `First`.

Comment: I have no other suggestions. I'm not familiar with `gorm`'s internals to know why exactly it's complaining.

Comment: Nil isn't the issue either. Thanks for your time. I really appreciate it!